# GLSL Uniform in a uniform block - how to access?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, block, uniform

I got a GLSL Shader with those uniform variables:

```
#version 150
layout (shared) uniform GlobalData {
  uniform mat4 worldMatrix;
  uniform mat4 projMatrix;
  // ...
};
```

How do I set those two matrices from my program? Unfortunately I can not edit the GLSL code since I am only writing a plugin for an existing application.

I tried:

```
glGetUniformLocation(program, "GlobalData.worldMatrix");
glGetUniformLocation(program, "worldMatrix");
```

neither works.

Teh GlobalData block has quite a lot more other uniforms that I don't want to change - all I care about is the worldMatrix.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I am only writing a plugin for an existing application.

Then you don't. Not unless you can access the buffer object that the plugin will use to store those matrices.

`GlobalData` is a [uniform block](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)); it represents the shader-side of a [UBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object). The C++ side will store the uniform data in a buffer object. So unless your application gives you access to that buffer, there's nothing you can do about it.

You might be able to binding your own buffer, but unless the application is designed to let you override its buffers, it will probably override whatever you bind before rendering takes place.